# "Fetch failed loading" - fetch works in Postman but fails in Chrome & Safari

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, fetch, create-react-app

**Update:** Fixed. It looks like the request was coming back as a 503 (as it should), then my app refreshed and displayed the non-error message: "Fetch failed loading". I just wasn't seeing the response because of the refresh.

---

I am not able to make a fetch request from my locally-hosted Create-React-App to my Heroku-hosted Node server.

My Node server has CORS enabled. If I make a POST request via Postman, I get an appropriate response (503, because currently there is no database hooked up, so the data is not being saved. If I should be sending back a different response, let me know). My Postman request has `'application/json'` as the content-type, no authorization, and a body of `{ "rating": "5", "zipcode": "0" }`.

However, when I make a POST request from my React app, I get a message in my console: **"Fetch failed loading: OPTIONS "https://shielded-gorge-69158.herokuapp.com/feedback"."** There is no associated error, only the message. There is no information about the request in my Network panel.

The fetch request works when I do it locally, from localhost:3000 (my app) to localhost:5000 (my server). It only fails when I try to make the request to the (otherwise identical) server hosted on Heroku.

This is what the fetch request looks like:

```
return fetch('https://shielded-gorge-69158.herokuapp.com/feedback', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ rating: userRating, zipcode: userZip })
}).then(res => {
if (!res.ok) {
  throw new Error('Error:', res.statusText);
}
  return res;
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Edit: I'm continuing to research and it seems like Postman shouldn't/doesn't make preflight requests (https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2845). So perhaps that is the issue — but why would the request be working when my server is local, but not when it is hosted on Heroku?

Comment: Can you add a bit more from your code and try adding a `catch` after `then` to `fetch`. Maybe a more detailed error can show whats wrong.

Comment: When you make request from local to local than it doesn't check for CORS, when you make request from postman it make given verb (post, put, delete, get, ...) immediately. When you make it from one domain to another (local to heroku) and do it from browser, before verb browser makes options request to check which headers are allowed and other things...

Answer (score 1):

use 'Content-Type' instead of 'Content-type'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header

Explanation: when you use incorrect case then it is considered as a custom header and hence, a preflight request is sent in such cases. Now if OPTIONS request is implemented on server with correct cors spec then next POST will be sent, else it wont be sent and request will fail. More on this in above links.